# IBM Cloud Developer Tool: idt build/bx dev build causing error (OCI runtime exec failed ...)

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-tools

I'm getting an error running `bx dev build` in my Node.js project folder, specifically:

```
[hafiz@Ubuntu ~/FSFTM/code/TaskListApp] $ sudo bx dev build
Getting service credentials for the project.
OK
OK
Deleting the container named 'tasklistapp-express-tools' ...
Creating image tasklistapp-express-tools based on Dockerfile-tools...
OK                    
Creating a container named 'tasklistapp-express-tools' from that image...
OK
Starting the 'tasklistapp-express-tools' container...
OK
Building the project in the current directory started at Fri Dec 22 22:03:35 2017
FAILED                
Failed to build the project.

Dumping output from the command: 
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:295: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:86: executing setns process caused \"exit status 22\"": unknown
```

Right before these, I ran `bx login --sso` and `bx target --cf`. Can't tell what the issue is exactly, I suspect it's something to do with Docker. I'm running this on an Ubuntu 16.04. Installed idt by running `curl -sL https://ibm.biz/idt-installer | bash`. Here's the version of bx:

```
[hafiz@Ubuntu ~/FSFTM/code/TaskListApp] $ bx -v
bx version 0.6.4+41cb1aa-2017-12-19T03:46:07+00:00
```

Not too sure what else I should include in this, I'm kinda stumped. The project builds fine by running `npm install`, `npm run build` and `npm run start`. I'd give additional info if I knew what would be useful! Anyone with a clue what the error really means or if I missed something?

As requested by joe, here's the trace:

```
[hafiz@Ubuntu ~/FSFTM/code/TaskListApp] $ bx dev build --trace
Getting service credentials for the project.
[http] 2017/12/25 15:15:52 gorequest.go:1049: HTTP Request: GET /scaffolder/api/generator/02810082-65bd-471d-8a1d-e2cb60dca916/status HTTP/1.1
Host: mobileprojectscaffolder.ng.bluemix.net
Content-Type: application/json

[http] 2017/12/25 15:15:53 gorequest.go:1078: HTTP Response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Language: en-US
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Mon, 25 Dec 2017 07:16:07 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
X-Backside-Transport: OK OK
X-Global-Transaction-Id: 868943159
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0

28
{"status":"NONEXISTENT","messages":null}
0

FAILED
An error occurred while getting the service credentials for the project.
Error: Remote files for this project no longer exist. A new project will have to be generated.

FAILED
An error occurred while getting the service credentials for the project.
Error: Remote files for this project no longer exist. A new project will have to be generated.
Using these variable values:
01: ContainerName string = 
02: ContainerNameRun string = tasklistapp-express-run
03: ContainerNameTools string = tasklistapp-express-tools
04: HostPathRun string = .
05: HostPathTools string = .
06: ContainerPathRun string = /app
07: ContainerPathTools string = /app
08: BuildCmdRun string = npm install
09: BuildCmdDebug string = npm install
10: TestCmd string = npm run test
11: DebugCmd string = npm run debug
12: RunCmd string = 
13: ContainerPortMap string = 3000:3000
14: ContainerPortMapDebug string = 5858:5858
15: ImageNameTools string = tasklistapp-express-tools
16: ImageNameRun string = tasklistapp-express-run
17: DockerfileRun string = Dockerfile
18: DockerfileTools string = Dockerfile-tools
19: ContainerMountsRun []map[string]string = [map[./node_modules_linux:/app/node_modules]]
20: ContainerMountsTools []map[string]string = [map[./node_modules_linux:/app/node_modules]]
21: IsDebug bool = false
22: IsTrace bool = true
23: Version string = 0.0.3
24: DeployTarget string = buildpack
25: IsForce bool = false
26: Language string = 
27: IbmCluster string = 
28: ChartPath string = chart/tasklistapp
29: DockerRegistry string = 
30: GeneratedID string = 02810082-65bd-471d-8a1d-e2cb60dca916
31: CredsFilepath string = server/localdev-config.json, vcap-local.js, credentials.json, localdev-config.json
32: NoOpen bool = false
33: WebAppRoot string = 
34: ContainerShell string = /bin/sh
35: ContainerShellTarget string = tools
Deleting the container named 'tasklistapp-express-tools' ...
Creating image tasklistapp-express-tools based on Dockerfile-tools...
Image will have user hafiz with id 1000 added
Step 1/12 : FROM ibmcom/ibmnode

 ---> 9db33a417145
Step 2/12 : ENV PORT 3000

 ---> Using cache
 ---> 882e62064ece
Step 3/12 : WORKDIR "/app"

 ---> Using cache
 ---> c0584b52956d
Step 4/12 : COPY . /app

 ---> Using cache
 ---> aad43758bec8
Step 5/12 : COPY run-dev /bin

 ---> Using cache
 ---> 742251038857
Step 6/12 : EXPOSE 3000

 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0d2790971939
Step 7/12 : CMD ["/bin/bash"]

 ---> Using cache
 ---> b8774ff51b14
Step 8/12 : ARG bx_dev_user=root

 ---> Using cache
 ---> 151098ec1756
Step 9/12 : ARG bx_dev_userid=1000

 ---> Using cache
 ---> 118442698498
Step 10/12 : RUN BX_DEV_USER=$bx_dev_user

 ---> Using cache
 ---> b697f05b3ff3
Step 11/12 : RUN BX_DEV_USERID=$bx_dev_userid

 ---> Using cache
 ---> 25c4ed895b04
Step 12/12 : RUN if [ $bx_dev_user != "root" ]; then useradd -ms /bin/bash -u $bx_dev_userid $bx_dev_user; fi

 ---> Using cache
 ---> ee1461ba1f16
Successfully built ee1461ba1f16
Successfully tagged tasklistapp-express-tools:latest
OK
Creating a container named 'tasklistapp-express-tools' from that image...
OK
Starting the 'tasklistapp-express-tools' container...
OK
Building the project in the current directory started at Mon Dec 25 15:15:56 2017
Executing command 'cd /app; npm install' on container tasklistapp-express-tools using user hafiz
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:295: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:86: executing setns process caused \"exit status 22\"": unknown
FAILED
Failed to build the project.

FAILED
Failed to build the project.
Stopping the 'tasklistapp-express-tools' container...
OK
```

Comment: Can you try running with the `--trace`? i.e. `bx dev build --trace`? You should probably not be running the command with sudo either.

Comment: Hi Joe, merry Christmas! Couldn't add the trace in this comment, see the above-edited question to see the trace results. Tried running with and without sudo with similar results.

Comment: Hi Hafiz, I just got back from Christmas break. Let me forward the logs to the CLI development team.

Comment: Thanks for the help Joe, hope to hear from the dev team soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From doing some research, the line 295 that is reporting the problem in the open source `container_linux.go` seems to be associated with user file permissions.  From your description, it looks like your system probably has some files owned by `root` that are not accessible now when you run the command with your own user account (as shown in the logs you provided).  I suspect some `chown`s will get you building just fine.

FYI

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI that the service credentials failure is harmless for the build.

I see in your last `build` you did not use `sudo`, that is good.  To debug this a little further, have you attempted to build a project for another language?  For example Java or Swift?  So far, I'm unable to reproduce the failure.

Thanks

Comment: Hello Steve, no I haven't tried using different languages for my project.

Answer (score 0):

Was there a reason that you were trying to run `bx dev build` using `sudo`?   Did you run `bx dev create` under `sudo` also?  This sounds like a permissions issue.

The error message is actually coming from Docker, not internal to the IBM Developer Tools executable:

`OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:295: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:86: executing setns process caused \"exit status 22\"": unknown`